# How to implement list filter functionality for mobile use case

Tags: mobile, lists, mobile-application, filter, drop-down-list

I have a list of vehicles in a mobile application. The user needs to be able to filter the list of vehicles with a few rules/requirements:

- User must be able to filter the list of vehicles i.e search for a vehicle or select one fro a list.
- User must be able to select and view one or multiple vehicles at a time.
- Must try stick to OS default search / filtering functionality and UI. Specifically for iOS and Android.
- Must be quick and easy for the user to filter. Not a lot of steps in the process.

Other info: 
- Most customers have 3-7 vehicles in their list in total. 
- There are a few customers who have up to 30 vehicles in their list to select from, so they need to be catered for too but are the minority.

What is the best way to do the vehicle filter without adding too many steps for the user?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to add a filter button right under the search field. When the user taps it, the filtering options will cover the entire screen. This way, the user can focus on all the parameters that the filtering system offers. Then, after applying the filter provide multiple ways of displaying the results such as (by how recent it was added, price, availability etc.)

As to selecting multiple results, provide a checkbox with each result item and also a top bar where the user is informed how many results were selected.